Can I recover the log-odds for each reference group in a logistic model?
Say I performed logistic regression with two binary variables $x, y$ giving the model:
$$ M(x, y) := ax + by + c. $$
Here $c$ is the log-odds when both $x, y$ are equal to zero. Can we instead find $d, e$ where $d$ is the log-odds when $x$ is zero and $e$ is the log-odds when $y$ is zero:
$$ M(x, y) := (ax + d) + (by + e) $$

Certainly.  But from what information do you want to "recover" these results?  Would this perhaps be a question about a particular statistical software platform?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
